# React Typescript keep getting invalid hook call and don't know how to solve?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have been trying to solve an invalid hook call error on my code. After reading countless articles and blogs on how to handle hook errors I still don't know what's wrong. I am rather new to Typescript and I still find some of its features and concepts quite alien to me.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  alpha,
  AppBar,
  InputBase,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Theme,
  Badge,
  Avatar,
} from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Mail, Search, Notifications, Cancel } from "@mui/icons-material";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  logoLg: {
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
    },
  },
  logoSm: {
    display: "block",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  },
  search: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    width: "50%",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      display: (props?: any) => (props.open ? "flex" : "none"),
      width: "70%",
    },
  },
  input: {
    color: "white",
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  cancel: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  },
  icons: {
    alignItems: "center",
    display: (props?: any) => (props.open ? "none" : "flex"),
  },
  badge: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  searchButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  },
}));
const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  // can pass our state as props to use css boolean values
  const classes = useStyles({ open });
  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed">
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
        {/* Variant is style, component is tag */}
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.logoLg}>
          Vagabond Connect
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.logoSm}>
          VC
        </Typography>
        <div className={classes.search}>
          <Search />
          <InputBase placeholder="Search..." className={classes.input} />
          <Cancel className={classes.cancel} onClick={() => setOpen(false)} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.icons}>
          <Search
            className={classes.searchButton}
            onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
          />
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary" className={classes.badge}>
            <Mail />
          </Badge>
          <Badge badgeContent={2} color="secondary" className={classes.badge}>
            <Notifications />
          </Badge>
          <Avatar
            alt="Remy Sharp"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589285874275-c5b16f4b3f8a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2835&q=80"
          />
        </div>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Here is the error that shows after my code complies:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: This code works fine for me in code sandbox are there any other errors anywhere else?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace and the code where you use `Navbar`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the feedback. I ended up switching to Material UI v4 and now it works. Not sure what was wrong with the v5 usage...